# If a game is offered for free on Playstation Now, how do I just buy it instead?

Tags: ps4, playstation-now

I just got a PS4, and I was thinking of downloading Katamari Forever off the Playstation Store.  I see that it's free for PS Now subscribers, but I don't want to start a subscription - I just want to pay the $7.99 it's listed at on the store page.

But, on the page itself, there doesn't seem to be any option to just buy it - I can only "Play for Free on PS Now".

I know I could just cancel the subscription, but I don't want to go through that hassle - I just want to buy the game and have it on my PS4 account, intact with save data and not having to pay a subscription to play it.

Is there an option to opt out of the PS Now download that I am missing?

Comment: If you need to pay for subscription to access a game for free, then it's not free!

Comment: @arghtype Exactly why I'm trying to avoid a subscription!

Comment: Incidentally, for anyone reading this, I eventually just decided to turn off auto-subscription for PS Now - you have to go into Settings > Account Management > Account Information > PlayStation Subscriptions and select "Playstation Now", which will turn off the auto-resubscribe, but allow you to keep playing the free trial if you want.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Unfortunately, in this situation, there is no way to opt out of subscribing to PS Now to play the game. PS Now is a streaming service that allows you to play any PS2, PS3, and PS4 games it provides as long as you have the subscription to the service.

In this situation, you are wanting to purchase Katamari Forever and play it on your PS4. The reason why you cannot opt out of subscribing to PS Now is because Katamari Forever does not have a PS4 release. Katamari Forever was only released for the PS3 and then added to the PS Now service some time in 2017.

Comment: Why does it list a price on the store page, and then say it's available for free on PS Now, if PS Now is required to even own it?

Comment: @Zibbobz My guess is that it is, for some reason, listing the PS3 version and price of the game. I actually can't verify that because it doesn't appear at all in the [store](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/search/katamari) for me

Comment: @Wondercricket: The link is [here](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP0700-NPUB90277_00-KATAMIPARENTPROD), but it's not purchasable even without PS Now because it was never made a digital release. The only way to play it is thru PS Now, or by buying a physical copy for PS3.

Comment: You should maybe point out that playstation now isn't the same as playstation plus. It sounds like maybe the two are being confused.